# Getting Win32Error while saving image object to a file (GDI+)

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi+

I receive Win32Error when try to save my bitmap e.g. in the root of C: but it’s Ok when I saving image to my default Pictures folder.

```
Status res = newBitmap.Save(L"C:\\new.png",&pngClsid); // res = Win32Error(7)

Status res = newBitmap.Save(L"C:\\Users\\username\\Pictures\\new.png",&pngClsid); //res = Ok(0)
```

Why and how to avoid this behavior?

(VS2012, Win7 64, MFC project)

Comment: Perhaps a permission issue? c:\ might only be accessible with administrative privileges

Comment: I have administrative privileges and haven’t any restrictions.

Comment: Did you run your code as Administrator or under a user account which may gain administrative privileges with UAC? If latter try first option

Comment: Thank you! Run as administrator solved the problem. Anyway, it is strange because I able to copy files to this location but unable to save files here. Other apps also deny saving files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Visual Studio as an Administrator solved the problem